# get BLOB image from MySql into CSS inline style

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have a php script, which contain `div` html tag. and I want to set `css background-image` from MySql to each divs.
**My Wrong Code:**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_Image = $row['blob'];
    echo "<div class='avatar' style='background-image :url(\"data:image/jpeg;base64, base64_encode($user_Image)\");'></div>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
      <?php
require 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_Image = $row['blob'];
    ?>
    <div class="avatar" style="background-image :url(data:image/jpeg;base64, base64_encode(<?php echo $user_Image;?>)")></div>
<?php     
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Sir, your answer probably right to me, but now i want to save my blob image into a new record which is also blob, please how can i do this. thank you.